# How to change language backend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend

good morning, could you help me how to change the language of the backend part of **magento 2**, or know where it is played in order to change it, I have found several modules of languages but some important parts are not complete, thank you very much to all and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your account (profile) settings for your user and switch there. You can also set the language while you add a new user.